# How can I get scrollbars on Picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, scrollbar, picturebox

I have `PictureBox picture`.

I use:

```
picture.Size = bmp.Size;
picture.Image = bmp;
```

Let's say there are two integers `maxWidth` and `maxHeigth`.
I want to add vertical/horizontal scrollbar to `picture` when its size exceeds `maxWidth` and/or `maxHeight`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

You can easily do it with a `Panel` Control

Insert a panel to your form, say panel1 and set

`panel1.AutoScroll = true;`

insert a `PictureBox` to the `Panel`, say picture and set

```
picture.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
```

and set the Image

```
picture.Image = bmp;
```

Comment: This is a nice answer because if you set the panel to be anchored to the form, the panel will expand as the form expands, showing and hiding the scrollbars as necessary.

Comment: I would add to binil's answer, the following: the picturebox has to have the anchor not set to right or bottom. Setting the anchor to right prevents the display of the horizontal scrollbar. Setting it to bottom prevents the display of the vertical scrollbar.

Comment: Mike, verify that pictureBox dock should be set to None. I had mine set to Fill and did not see any scrollbars but when I changed it to none the scrollbars appeared.

Comment: I've the same problem, the pictureBox dock is set to None but If I set the SizeMode to AutoSize no scrollbars are shown

Comment: Yep same issue here, you cannot set SizeMode to AutoSize in the later versions.  Setting it to Normal works as expected.

Comment: I also set the panel1's AutoSize to false because it became as big as my screen.

Comment: Resuming ('cause i've done a lot of experiments), and this worked for me:
Panel: Autosrcoll: true, Dock: fill
Picturebox: Dock: none; Anchor: Top, Left; SizeMode: AutoSize

Answer (score 5):

I got it to work by also putting a picturebox inside a panel control, I set the Panel's AutoScroll property to true, but I also set the Panel's Autosize property to True, and the Panel's Dock property to Fill (that way when the user resizes the form - so will the Panel).  For the Picturebox, I set it's Dock property to None, and the SizeMode to Autosize (so it resizes also when the Panel and form Resizes.  It worked like a charm, the Picturebox has Scrollbars and when the user resizes the form - everything is still placed correctly!

Comment: Thanks, the only way it worked for me (VS2017) was PictureBox:  Dock = None and SizeMode = AutoSize. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a project where a guy built an `ImagePanel` user control that you can drop onto a form; it gives you scrollbars and zoom capability.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/YLScsImagePanel.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It works to me.

```
PictureBox picture = new PictureBox();
picture.Image=Image.FromFile("image.bmp");
picture.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
Panel panel = new Panel();
panel.Size=new Size(800,600);
panel.Location=new Point(0,0);
panel.AutoScroll=true;
panel.Controls.Add(picture);
this.Controls.Add(panel);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion is to put the picturebox inside a FlowlayoutPanel .

Set the Auto scroll of the FlowlayoutPanel to true and set the picture size mode to normal

Using a FlowlayoutPanel makes sure the image is always at 0,0 in the panel