# PictureBox does not change its size

Tags: winforms, image, picturebox

I have a `PictureBox` and a `Button` inside a `Form`. The `PictureBox` fill the `Form` and the `SizeMode` property is set to `StretchImage`.

When i click the button I want to change the image size (bigger), and **I want also that the scrollbars appear**.

So, I change the `Size` property of my `PictureBox` on the click event:

```
pictureBox1.Size = new Size(800, 800);
```

but this code does not have any effect.
Why?

I also tried to redraw the image itself (using GDI commands), but in this way the scrollbars do not appear.

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you setting the dock mode of your picture box?

Comment: @MarkHall yes it fills (Dock = Fill) the form.

Comment: You will not be able to get scrollbars then, because with your SizeMode set to StretchImage and your Dock set to fill the PictureBox will always be the size of your client area and your Picture will be sized to fit it.

Comment: @MarkHall so, what I have to do to resize my image having the scrollbars?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710145/how-can-i-get-scrollbars-on-picturebox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set:

```
pictureBox1.Bounds = this.ClientRectangle;
pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.None;
```

for your `PictureBox` and you will be able to resize the `PictureBox` itself.