# Is it possible to stretch picture horizontal only in PictureBox with Vertical scrollbar in WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scrollbar, picturebox

I have a `PictureBox` inside the `Panel` with picture box `Dock = DockStyle.Fill`

When I assign picture into the `PictureBox`, picture is stretch horizontal to fit the space available and need a vertical scrollbar to scroll the image.

**Note:** Panel size may change at run time (so, obviously `PictureBox` size too).

This [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710145/how-can-i-get-scrollbars-on-picturebox) suggest to get both scroll bars. But, my question is different.

Please help me out.

Comment: If you want a scrollbar then you do **not** want DockStyle.Fill

Comment: @HansPassant Its not really a duplicate of that question as OP does not want a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: @HansPassant My question is different, I don't want both scroll bars. Please remove duplicate..

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu If you do not have a solution yet I suggest: re-open a new question, clearly state you don't want the horizontal scrollbar (even more clearly :)) and I will post my answer as I already have a working solution

Comment: @EpicKip yes sure. i will post my new question and paste the link of it. thanks in advance

Comment: @EpicKip http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42857528/is-it-possible-to-stretch-picture-in-picturebox-without-horizontal-scrollbar-and is my new question

Comment: Please refer answer for this question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42857528/is-it-possible-to-stretch-picture-in-picturebox-without-horizontal-scrollbar-and/42857567?noredirect=1#comment72821639_42857567