# Is it possible to stretch picture in PictureBox without horizontal scrollbar and only Vertical scrollbar in WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scrollbar, picturebox

I have a `PictureBox` inside the Panel with picture box `Dock = DockStyle.Fill`.

When I assign picture into the `PictureBox`, picture is stretch horizontal to fit the space available and need a vertical scrollbar to scroll the image. I do not need of **horizontal scrollbar** in it.

Please do not make this question as duplicate.. I have clearly mentioned that I only need of vertical scrollbar with run time resizing option of the panel.

Note: Panel size may change at run time (so, obviously `PictureBox` size too).

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses a simple resize method which you can call whenever it should update its size.

**prerequisites:**

- Turn off the docking for the PictureBox
- Set the AutoScroll property of the Panel to true

**Resizing method:**

```
private void panel1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ResizePb();
}

private void ResizePb()
{
    //Make the pciturebox as wide as the panel, keep in mind the scrollbars
    pictureBox1.Width = panel1.Width - SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth - 5; 
    //Calculate the aspect ratio of the image based on its new width
    var aspect = (double)panel1.Width / pictureBox1.Image.Width;
    //Set height according to aspect ratio
    var height = Convert.ToInt32(aspect * pictureBox1.Image.Height);
    pictureBox1.Height = height;
}
```

Comment: No problem, I suggest using the panel's resize event as I did. (Because you said panel size might change)

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu If you keep it docked it will not work btw, this code will 'dock' it for you (make it max size for panel

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu Almost forgot, turn on autoScroll on your panel!

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu Glad to help, thank you for accepting my answer